# Targeted CSS files or fallbacks in the CSS

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, modernizr

I'm looking at rewriting an existing site (purely for learning) into more manageable code and making use of some of the 'newer' technologies (specifically; flexbox, gradients, mobile first responsive design), but a fair (5%) proportion of my readers are limited in their browser choice (IE8), therefore, I need to continue to be supportive of their needs; so progressive enhancement seems to be sensible; but...

I very quickly end up in a place where huge amounts of my CSS are redundant for certain browsers - for example; using multiple background gradients, fall back to a single gradient, fallback to a dataURI image (and if I want to go further, then fallback to a url image). All of the code is in the CSS file - increasing its size.

So, it seems to me that there are a number of options as to how to manage this:

- Just ignore it - assume that the size of the CSS is insignificant in the grand scheme of things (compared to additional HTTP requests); hence use fallbacks in the CSS either through classes added by something like Modernizr or just simple CSS fallbacks
- Load a specific CSS file for each case (I came up with 4 cases - and they don't equate to versions of IE due to FF's poor Flexbox support). Could something like yesnope.js be used to load just one CSS file? What's the impact in page speed? How do you deal with no-js situations
- Modular loading of CSS files; one base file + 1 or 2 files (probably 2; gradients and layout) based on Modernizr outputs - more HTTP requests, but asynchronous, less overall file size

The question is easy (but the answer may not be!), which approach is recommended and why?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the file sizes of CSS files unless the redundancy is in like, 10s of thousands of lines... When designing your own it's good to stay organized, but if you had to refactor existing CSS every time you worked on legacy code... oh what a repetitive nightmare that would be. Most sites use multiple stylesheets so you don't have to load just ONE massive stylesheet every time though, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Agree with HC_, and also suggest looking at a workflow that includes SASS or Compass. That allows you to use nicely-refactored `@mixin` and `@extend` directives when writing and maintaining the source, which compiles to your repetitive CSS.

Comment: I'm using SASS and Compass. The `@mixin` and `@extend` work really well for me. The question may well come down to; is having one main sheet with a feature dependent second/third a bad idea?